# How to await for the stream event to get processed in the unit-test?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, stream

The unit-test implies that after some item was passed to a `Sink` object through the `add` method, than some operation will be performed in response to it.

```
class Subject {
  final StreamController<Item> _itemStreamController = StreamController();
  Sink<Item> get itemsSink => _itemStreamController.sink;
  Stream<Item> get _itemsStream => _itemStreamController.sink;
  final SomeService _service;

  Subject(this._service) {
    _itemsStream.listen((item) => _service.processItem(item));
  }
}
```

And the unit test itself:

```
test('description', () async {
  final Item givenItem = Item("givenValue");
  final SomeService givenService = MockSomeService();
  final Subject subject = Subject(givenService);
  subject.itemsSink.add(givenItem);
  verify(givenService.add(givenItem));
});
```

And as you can understand the event looping thread firstly processes `verify` instructions and only then dispatches the event to the listener.

If I just insert `await Future.value(null);` between sink interaction and method invocation verification than all works like a charm. Still, this solution is quite ugly.

Does the unit-testing framework itself offer something to schedule verification at the end of event loop? Or any measures to get this unit-test passed without resorting to something like `await Future.value(null);`?

Comment: See [the `StreamMatcher` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/test_api/StreamMatcher-class.html) for examples.